# How to melt/transpose my data a certain way?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is the dummy code.

```
x = data.frame(
  control_type = c("case","control","control"),
  gender = c("M","F","M"),
  short  = c(1,2,3),
  medium = c(5,7,4),
  long = c(9,12,10)
)
```

I want to get this data frame to look like the image below, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. In other words, convert the top part of the image to the bottom. Possibly using melt in some way? I am not sure.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyfl0.png

Comment: Does the image looks like two separate data frames.  Is that the intended result?

Comment: The answer to the _related_ answer is out of date. The melt/reshape was superseded by gather/spread and that is in the process of being replaced with pivot_longer/pivot_wider.

Comment: @GcL The linked dupe target post is the post that should be referred to for wide/long reshaping. It is kept up-to-date with the newer `tidyr` options.

Comment: @MauritsEvers it's at least one generation out of date as pivot_longer is the most recent.

Comment: @GcL `spread` and `gather` are still valid. They are retired not deprecated, and `tidyr` will continue to include `spread`/`gather`. The dupe target **does include** the newer `pivot_wider`/`pivot_longer` options!

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) and remove the 'value' column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = short:long, names_to = c('Length')) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-value)
```